# How to stop Elixir application started in "detached" mode?

Tags: elixir

I started my app using the following command:

```
elixir --erl "-detached" -S mix phx.server
```

How can I stop/restart the process?

Comment: I usually kill the process on port, it is easier: `fuser -k 8080/tcp`

Comment: @Daniel Feel free to add your answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer was found [here](https://elixirforum.com/t/terminating-a-detached-elixir-os-process/18664).

Assuming a UNIX-like system:

> ps aux | grep elixir

to find the process-id of the OS-process that runs the Erlang VM that has loaded elixir and your phoenix application, and then

> kill number

to stop it. number is the number in the second column of the output of ps aux (the first column containing the name of the unix-user that owns, i.e. started, the process).
Afterwards you can try ps aux | grep elixir again to make sure it is no longer there.

In an actual production environment, it is advisable that you instead set up e.g. a systemd entry that manages the process, which makes it a lot easier to start/stop/restart/autostart-at-boot and monitor it.